# How to apply javascripts to element wich has been overwrited by jquery .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here I have an example:

```js
$('#key').on('click', function(){
  $('.task').html("<button id='key'>Button</button>"+Date());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='task'>
  <button id='key'>Button</button>
</div>
```

How I can apply javascript for overwriting element and get different time for each button press?

Comment: @David looks like wrong duplicate.

Comment: use eventDelegation as explained here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: How so?  In what way is what the OP trying to accomplish different from the linked duplicate?

Comment: @David Yeah. Just thinking about it :) But OP going in a wrong way it seems

Comment: Why are you replacing the button every time anyway? Totally unnecessary.

Comment: The question is: Does it possible to apply javascript to element which has been overwrited?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly there is no need to ovveride button here. Do not ovveride button. Use a span for date.

```js
$('#key').on('click', function(){
  $('.datestr').html(Date());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='task'>
  <button id='key'>Button</button>
  <span class='datestr'></span>
</div>
```